# Is there a way to position this ribbon over an image in html email so that it works on clients like Outlook?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, html-email

After doing research I'm coming to the realization that this might not be possible in all clients but I wanted to ask if anything has changed recently in the email world that would let me create something like in the image below. I want that little blue ribbon with text to appear on top of the image. From what I've seen it doesnt look like negative margins or absolute positioning has the support I need. Is there some hacky workaround people have come up with for something like this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome Ben! Styling emails is always a pain. Can you show us what you've tried so far. Or provide some of your existing HTML/CSS?

Comment: When all else fails in styling emails, just make it all an image ;)

Comment: +1 for making the whole thing a single image file. Even if you get the overlay to work (using nested tables for example), the positioning may differ between email clients. Making it all one image locks in your formatting.

Comment: You should be able to do this with VML. VML will allow you to do background images specifically for Outlook. All others will use normal CSS background or background attribute. If you edit your question to add in the code you have tried then someone can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by others...
You could use the VML option, however the padding used to push the tab down could vary between email clients, so definitely worth testing out.

A set height on a table cell and using vertical align bottom could be another method to test, but personally I always stick to padding as it's always been solid for me.
Although I should note... I don't think I've ever had to align something to the very bottom of a bg image. I'm usually centering or padding elements from the top of the image.

Good place to start though:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">                        
   <tr>                          
      <td background="https://via.placeholder.com/359x174" bgcolor="#00e5ff" height="174" styke="width:100%;max-width:359px;height:174px;" valign="top" width="359">
         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
         <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:359px;height:174px;">
         <v:fill type="tile" src="https://via.placeholder.com/359x174" color="#00e5ff" />
         <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
         <![endif]-->
         <div>                              
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">                                
               <tr>                                  
                  <td style="padding:139px 0 0 0;">                                    
                     <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">                                      
                        <tr>                                        
                           <td align="center" bgcolor="#2979ff" style="font-family:arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:15px; line-height:20px; font-weight:600; color:#ffffff; padding:8px 15px; border-radius:0 7px 0 7px;">
                              Earn $10 off
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </table>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
         </v:textbox>
         </v:rect>
         <![endif]-->
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```